# checking the enclosed tuple

Tags: python, list

this code returns True

```
a = [('e', 4), ('r', 2), (' ', 2), ('h', 2), ('A', 1), ('t', 1), ('y', 1)]
print(('e', 4) in a) # True
```

and if I don't know the number next to 'e', ​​how do I check if that letter is on the list

```
print(('e',) in a) # False
```

Comment: `any(letter == 'e' for letter, _ in a)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to brute-force the search.

Check if any of the tuples in the list have the first member as `'e'`

```
a = [('e', 4), ('r', 2), (' ', 2), ('h', 2), ('A', 1), ('t', 1), ('y', 1)]

print(any(tup[0] == 'e' for tup in a))
```

Which gives:

```
True
```

Comment: "You need to brute force the search" is misleading IMHO since `in` on a list basically does the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the `list` to a `dict` first:

```py
a = [('e', 4), ('r', 2), (' ', 2), ('h', 2), ('A', 1), ('t', 1), ('y', 1)]
b = dict(a)

print(('e', 4) in a)

print('e' in b)
```

Outputs `True` twice.

This code takes advantage of a `dict` which will directly take a `list` of `tuples` and make the first element of each `tuple` into the keys. Then you can quickly search the keys of the resulting `dict`.

Comment: It might make sense to use a `dict` instead of list of tuples in the first place, but just converting to `dict` so that `in` works?

Comment: but this will not work if the nested tuples have 3 elements each, therefore brute-force is better

Comment: You gave every indication in your question that the tuples would all have two elements. Are you saying that the tuples could have any number of elements?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get the first components of every tuple. Then check using if `e` occurs in the resulting list using the existing approach.

```
a = [('e', 4), ('r', 2), (' ', 2), ('h', 2), ('A', 1), ('t', 1), ('y', 1)]
print('e' in [e[0] for e in a])
# True
```